# Discord.js bot errors after not being used for 30 minutes

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I don't know why, but all the commands work, interactions and everything. But if I were to stop using the bot and leave it online, come back to it and run another command, it just outputs this error and crashes.

```js
/home/yetnt/bots/mJb/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:640
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
            ^

DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (/home/yetnt/bots/mJb/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (/home/yetnt/bots/mJb/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:736:23)
    at async REST.request (/home/yetnt/bots/mJb/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1387:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.deferReply (/home/yetnt/bots/mJb/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:69:5) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 5, data: { flags: undefined } } },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1107289296546832485/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTEwNzI4OTI5NjU0NjgzMjQ4NTpNcmhrYWh0ZGdndzQ5SjJWT3BEYWNhWDNsMHIwT2YwaWxlVFMyclByd2ZuNWpLejNPSmEyOG14T3kwOXNZc3l5VnFHTkgwVUhKYW55Q0RmajlXb1NoSDgzUnNYN1pKZEFzNU9LR3puaFZKVm1XbjZJRHZydkVZTEpNcnRSUHBIdA/callback'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I restart the bot and it all works fine, all the commands and everything. But until it's left idling it does not work.
I wouldn't mind restarting the bot every time but this is getting annoying now.

`rob.js`

```js
const { ApplicationCommandOptionType, Client, Interaction, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')
const User = require('../../models/User')
const rndInt = require('../../utils/rndInt')
const Inventory = require('../../models/Inventory')
const [ comma, coin, shopify ] = require('../../utils/beatify')
const { newCooldown, checkCooldown } = require('../../utils/cooldown')

module.exports = {
    name:"rob",
    description:"Rob people for some quick cash",
    options: [
        {
            name:"victim",
            description:"robbery",
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
            required: true
        }
    ],
    blacklist: true,


    /**
    *
    * @param {Client} client
    * @param {Interaction} interaction
    */
    callback: async (client, interaction) => {

        try {
            await interaction.deferReply()
            let victimId = interaction.options.get("victim").value
            const sf = rndInt(1, 2) // 2 = success; 1 = failure

            let victim = await User.findOne({userId: victimId})
            let inventory = await Inventory.findOne({userId: victimId}) // victim's inventory
            const victimDm = await client.users.fetch(victimId).catch(() => null); // to dm the user.
            let author = await User.findOne({userId: interaction.user.id })

            if (victimId == interaction.user.id) {interaction.editReply( { embeds : [ new EmbedBuilder().setDescription("don't rob yourself.")]}); return};
            if (!author) {interaction.editReply( { embeds : [ new EmbedBuilder().setDescription("You cannot rob people when you've got nothing")]}); return}
            if (author.balance < 1000) {interaction.editReply( { embeds : [ new EmbedBuilder().setDescription("You cannot rob people when your balance is lower than 1000.")]}); return}
            if (!victim) {interaction.editReply( { embeds : [ new EmbedBuilder().setDescription("Leave them alone, they've got nothing :sob:")]}); return};
            if (victim.balance < 0) {interaction.editReply( { embeds : [ new EmbedBuilder().setDescription("This user is paying off their debts")]}); return};
            if (victim.balance <= 500) {interaction.editReply( { embeds : [ new EmbedBuilder().setDescription(`It aint worth it, they've only got ${coin(victim.balance)}`)]}); return};

            const cooldownResult = await checkCooldown('rob', interaction, EmbedBuilder);
            if (cooldownResult === 0) {
              return;
            }

            if (inventory) { // check if they have an inventory
                if (inventory.inv.shield.amt > 0 && inventory.inv.shield.hp > 0) {
                    let damage = rndInt(Math.ceil(inventory.inv.shield.hp / 2), inventory.inv.shield.hp)
                    await interaction.editReply( { embeds : [ new EmbedBuilder().setDescription(`You tried to rob them but this user had a shield! You damaged their shield by **${comma(damage)}%**`)]})
                    inventory.inv.shield.hp -= damage

                    await inventory.save()
                    if (inventory.inv.shield.hp == 0) {
                        inventory.inv.shield.amt -= 1
                        await interaction.followUp("You broke this user's shield.")
                        await inventory.save()
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
            
            const max = Math.floor(victim.balance / 2) // doing this so mfs dont get their whole ass robbed. 
            let sRob = rndInt(1, max) // user can only be robbed random amounts from 1 to half their balance
            let fRob = rndInt(Math.floor(author.balance / 2), author.balance) // if robbery failed deduct random amt between author/2 and author

            if (sf === 2) { // Succesful
                victim.balance -= sRob
                author.balance += sRob

                await victimDm.send({
                    embeds: [
                        new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle("You have been robbed from!")
                            .setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}> stole ${coin(sRob)} from you!`)
                            .setFooter({text: `Server = ${interaction.member.guild.name}`})
                    ]
                }).catch(() => null);

                await interaction.editReply({
                    embeds : [
                        new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle("Robbery :money_with_wings:")
                            .setDescription(`You stole a grand total of ${coin(sRob)} from <@${victimId}>. Leaving them with ${coin(victim.balance)}`)
                            .setColor("Green")
                            .setFooter({text: "You monster"})
                    ]
                })
            } else { // failed
                author.balance -= fRob
                victim.balance += fRob

                interaction.editReply({
                    embeds : [
                        new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle("Robbery")
                            .setDescription(`You tried robbing <@${victimId}> but they caught you before you could get away. You paid ${coin(fRob)} in fines to <@${victimId}>`)
                            .setColor("Red")
                            .setFooter({text: "I knew this wouldnt work."})
                    ]
                })
            }

            await author.save()
            await victim.save()

            await newCooldown('5min', interaction, 'rob')
        }  catch (error) {
            interaction.editReply('An error occured.')
            client.guilds.cache.get("808701451399725116").channels.cache.get("971098250780241990").send({ embeds : [
                new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle(`An error occured. Command name = ${interaction.commandName}`)
                .setDescription(`\`${error}\``)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({text:`Server ID : ${interaction.guild.id} | User ID : ${interaction.user.id} | Error was also logged to console.`})
            ]})
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

`handleCommands.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
const { devs, testServer } = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'config.json'));
const getLocalCommands = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'utils', 'getLocalCommands'));
const Blacklist = require('../../models/Blacklist')
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = async (client, interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

  const localCommands = getLocalCommands();

  try {
    const commandObject = localCommands.find(
      (cmd) => cmd.name === interaction.commandName
    );

    if (!commandObject) return;

    if (commandObject.devOnly) {
      if (!devs.includes(interaction.user.id)) {
        interaction.reply({
          content: 'Only developers are allowed to run this command.',
          ephemeral: true,
        });
        return;
      };
    };
     
    if (commandObject.blacklist) {
      let query = {
        userId: interaction.user.id
      };
      let blacklist = await Blacklist.findOne(query)
      
      if (blacklist) {
        if (blacklist.blacklisted === true) {
          interaction.reply("You've been blacklisted. Reason = " + `${blacklist.reason}`)
          return;
        };
      };
    };

    if (commandObject.testOnly) {
      if (!(interaction.guild.id === testServer)) {
        interaction.reply({
          content: 'This command cannot be ran here.',
          ephemeral: true,
        });
        return;
      }
    }

    if (commandObject.permissionsRequired?.length) {
      for (const permission of commandObject.permissionsRequired) {
        if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(permission)) {
          interaction.reply({
            content: 'Not enough permissions.',
            ephemeral: true,
          });
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    if (commandObject.botPermissions?.length) {
      for (const permission of commandObject.botPermissions) {
        const bot = interaction.guild.members.me;

        if (!bot.permissions.has(permission)) {
          interaction.reply({
            content: "I don't have enough permissions.",
            ephemeral: true,
          });
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    await commandObject.callback(client, interaction);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`There was an error running the command: `);
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

`cooldown.js`

```js
const { Interaction, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')
const Cooldown = require('../models/Cooldown');
const strToMilli = require('../utils/strToMilli')

/**
 * 
 * @param {String} time Can be a strin glike '2min' or '9d'
 * @param {Interaction} interaction 
 * @param {String} name The command's name
 * @returns 
 */
const newCooldown = async (time, interaction, name) => {
    let query = {
      userId: interaction.user.id
    };
    let date = Date.now();
    let cooldown = await Cooldown.findOne(query);
  
    if (cooldown && cooldown[name] && cooldown[name].getTime() > date) {
      return;
    }
  
    let cooldownTime;
    if (typeof time == "string") {
      cooldownTime = strToMilli(time);
    } else if (typeof time == "integer") {
      cooldownTime = time;
    } else {
      throw `wtf is "${time}"`;
    }
  
    if (cooldown) {
      cooldown[name] = new Date(date + cooldownTime);
      await cooldown.save();
    } else {
      const newCooldown = new Cooldown({
        ...query,
        [name]: new Date(date + cooldownTime)
      });
      await newCooldown.save();
    }
};
  


/**
 * 
 * @param {String} name The command's name
 * @param {Interaction} interaction 
 * @param {EmbedBuilder} EmbedBuilder
 * @returns 
 */
const checkCooldown = async (name, interaction, EmbedBuilder) => {
    let query = {
        userId: interaction.user.id
    }
    let date = Date.now()

    let cooldown = await Cooldown.findOne(query)

    if (cooldown && cooldown[name]) {
        let remainingTime = cooldown[name] - date
        let endTime = Math.floor((Date.now() + remainingTime) / 1000);
        if ( remainingTime > 0 ) {
            interaction.editReply({
                embeds: [
                    new EmbedBuilder()
                        .setTitle("Cooldown")
                        .setDescription(`Slow down bro. This command has a cooldown, you will be able to run this command <t:${endTime}:R>`)
                        .setColor("Random")
                ]
            })
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return
    }

}

module.exports = { newCooldown, checkCooldown }
```

Comment: Before somebody says your response replied too late, for every interaction i defer the reply then edit it later on.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your command handler and some more details of what command you are using when the bot crashes along with its code @yetnt

Comment: @dylanface i edited the file to include these. (it occurs with the rob command)

Comment: it looks like the problem is with this function here `await newCooldown('5min', interaction, 'rob')` likely when that cooldown finished you attempt to further interact with the interaction but after the 5 minutes on that cooldown is up the interaction would be expired. Can you edit your post again to include the `newCooldown()` definition and maybe attempt removing the cooldown and seeing if the problem still persists.

Comment: @dylanface I've edited the post again to include cooldown, and right now im removing cooldown, I'll update if the problem persists or ends

Comment: Nope, removed cooldown codes and nothing changed. Rob worked after starting the bot. But few minutes later, i tried it again and it just crashed the bot

Comment: does this only happen with the rob command? @YetNT

Comment: @dylanface I just tested it thoughout the day. Seemsto be every command

Comment: This must be due to your command handler then, taking a quick look at your `handleCommand.js` file it looks like the lead suspect is this function call `const localCommands = getLocalCommands();`. I suspect that this loads the command files and stores them in a map or array. Likely at some point the command is not getting unloaded and then when the same command comes in you are executing in the same scope as the previous execution. If you use a command then wait like 5 minutes and use it again does the same issue happen, or does it have to be an extended period of time? @YetNt

Comment: @dylanface no seems to be an extended time.

Comment: @dylanface I think i found the problem. When i use the bot i'm usually in an area where i have low internet connection. Like 2 to no bars low.So now and then my chromebook would disconnect and reconnect to the wifi. 
I left my chromebook next to the router(just as a test) came back after about 12 hours and it still works fine, so i'm assuming that was the issue